# windows form refresh - how can i make it smoother?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, refresh

I draw a small labyrinth on a windows-form and re-draw it with every keydown-event. How can i make it smoother? The drawing durates approx. one second and when you enter the arrow buttons you can see a short flickering on the form.

```
        public void Draw_Labyrinth()
        {
            this.Update();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            Controls.Clear();


            for (int i = 0; i < list_Elements_Y.Count; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < list_Elements_Y[i].list_Elements_X.Count; j++)
                {

                    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

                    pb.Location = list_Elements_Y[i].list_Elements_X[j].position;
                    pb.Name = list_Elements_Y[i].list_Elements_X[j].name;
                    pb.Size = list_Elements_Y[i].list_Elements_X[j].size;


                    if (pb.Location == characterPosition) 
                    {
                        pb.Image = Properties.Resources.character;
                    }
                    else if (pb.Name == "item")
                    {
                        pb.Image = Properties.Resources.item;
                    }
                    else if (pb.Name == "wall")
                    {
                        pb.Image = Properties.Resources.wall;
                    }

                    Controls.Add(pb);


                    Application.DoEvents();
                    this.Update();
                }

            }

            Application.DoEvents();
            this.ResumeLayout();

        }
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set `DoubleBuffered` to true?

Comment: You are probably drawing each sprite by sprite, try to batch static environment as one picturebox.

Comment: directly draw to a single picture box in sections...rather than using a series of picturebox controls

Comment: i set DoubleBuffered to true, that works! Now it is much better! Not perfect, but much better - thanks

Comment: "re-draw" means (for most people) "draw on a single device context/picture/bitmap", the code show re-creates whole bunch of controls. Creating control is definitely not expected to work blazingly fast (definitely on not expected to happen every keystroke), creating a lot of controls as you likely doing will be slow.

Answer (score 2):

Flickering in WinForms can typically be solved (or greatly improved) by setting `DoubleBuffered` to `true`.

This can be done in the VS Designer, or in the `Form` constructor.

A full second of drawing operations seems excessive. So if you could optimize that it would be a good idea.

Comment: @rfmodulator: No, it's conceptual. The fact that the whole tree is recreated is actually a part of why it is so slow. So, that's basically the *good idea* you're hinting for. It's just improving the advise - restarting the program would also be *a form of drawing*, surely you would advise against it ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Sorry, what were we arguing about again?

Comment: @rfmodulator: sorry, I am not arguing, I am just trying to help you out; by saying that Alexei has a point, blunt perhaps, but still valid - and it's not only semantics. Your last statement suggest performance should be improved - the crucial part is: controls are recreated - which is a large superset of "drawing", and hence, seriously slower than actual "drawing".

Comment: Creating controls involves much more than drawing.